# Creating text file with > inside from command line

Tags: windows, command-line

I need create text file with characters like < > from command line. More precisely it should be: `%1 < %2 > %3` Tried to use echo do to it, but when I type

```
echo %1 < %2 > %3 > output.txt
```

or

```
echo '%1 < %2 > %3' > aab.txt
```

error will occur. When I type

```
echo "%1 < %2 > %3" > output.txt
```

output.txt content will be `"%1 < %2 > %3"` (with double quotes inside).

I need content similar to last one but without double quotes inside file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `^` as escape character:

```
echo %1 ^< %2 ^> %3 > output.txt
```